# Javascript taking .innerHTML on indexOf checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable named 'options'. Whenever a user checks one of the checkboxes, I need 'options' to populate the string with the .innerHTML for each checked checkbox. For example, when Instagram and Google+ are checked, 'options' would = Instagram, Google+.

html:

```
<section id="extra-features">
    <div class="span3">
        <label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Review site monitoring
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Google+
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> LinkedIn
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Pinterest
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> FourSquare
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Tumblr
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Advertising
        </label>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="card-charge-info">
    Your card will be charged $<span id="payment-total">0</span> now, and your subscription will bill $<span id="payment-rebill">0</span> every month thereafter. You can cancel or change plans anytime.
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var price = 0,
    additional = 0,
    options = "",
    inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total'),
    total2 = document.getElementById('payment-rebill');

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.parentNode.className.split(" ").indexOf("checked") > -1 ? 1 : -1);
            additional += add
            total.innerHTML = price + additional;

        if (price == select.options[2].value) {
            total2.innerHTML = 0;
        }
        else {
            total2.innerHTML = price + additional;
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/LQpHQ/

Comment: my apologies, it was selected on accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend tabulating the information each time they change a check state. What you're doing now is problematic; currently you start at 0, but end up being in the negative (total price) quickly by checking and unchecking a couple of options.

Also, options, as a string, will become difficult to keep up with. I'd probbaly make that an array that you can add/remove from (but if you tabulate at the end, there's no worrying).

For example:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total'),
    total2 = document.getElementById('payment-rebill');

// Perform the summing
// Though I'm not sure where total is coming from, but you can work that out.
// And for now I have it alerting the options, but you can do whatever you'd like with that.
function sumItUp(){
    var ttl = 0, additional = 0, options = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if (inputs[i].checked){
            options.push(inputs[i].parentNode.textContent.trim());
            var n = new Number(inputs[i].value);
            if (!isNaN(n)) additional += n;
        }
    }
    total.innerHTML = ttl.toFixed(2);
    total2.innerHTML = (ttl + additional).toFixed(2);
    alert('Options:\n\n' + options.join(', '));
}

// bind events to sum it on every change
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', sumItUp);
}

// Polyfill for trim()
if (!String.prototype.trim){
    String.prototype.trim = function(){
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    };
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQpHQ/2/)

Comment: Brad, I am using a jquery plugin for the checkboxes that sets the value to - every time a checkbox is selected. that is why the current javascript acts weird in the fiddle. i was more looking for populating the options variable or array. thanks for looking out though

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `.innerHTML` to get the text of the checkbox since it doesn't contain any text. You'll want to use `.nextSibling` instead. Something like this should work:

```
var price = 0,
additional = 0,
options = "",
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
total  = document.getElementById('payment-total'),
total2 = document.getElementById('payment-rebill');

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var text = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
        if(options.indexOf(text) != -1) {
            options += text + ',';
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you'd also want to handle when a checkbox is unselected as well.